# Script editor is not able to access popover UI element in macOs version - Big Sur

Tags: scripting, applescript, accessibility-inspector

AppleScript code:

```
 tell process "EdgeMonitor"
     tell menu bar 2        
       UI elements      
     end tell
  end tell
```

When trying to access UI elements for a given application, we are getting different results on macOS Ventura and macOS Big Sur for the same app and same script.

We are specifically trying to access the popover UI element which is accessible in Ventura but not in Big Sur. Can someone please help here to check why this might be happening?

Thank you

UI elements in macOS Ventura:

menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2 of application process "EdgeMonitor" of application "System Events", pop over 1 of menu bar 2 of application process "EdgeMonitor" of application "System Events"

UI elements in macOS Big Sur:

menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2 of application process "EdgeMonitor" of application "System Events", menu bar item 2 of menu bar 2 of application process "EdgeMonitor" of application "System Events"

When trying to access UI elements for a given application, we are getting different results on macOS Ventura and macOS Big Sur for the same app and same script.

Comment: The UI layout of any given application (or the OS) is entirely up to the developer, and can (and frequently does) change with different versions.  For GUI scripting, you would need to explore the particular UI hierarchies to see what elements exist and how they are arranged.

Comment: I can confirm that red_menace‘s comment is a valid answer!